# Changing some values in an Array

Tags: php

Source array:

```
$source_array = array("email"=>"email@email.com", "name"=>"adem", "last_name"=>"genc", "username"=>"ademgenc", "age"=>"40", "issue"=>"php", "version"=>"12,50", "user_group"=>"2", "created"=>"2020-09-02 10:58:54");
```

Values to be changed array:

```
$values_to_be_changed_array = array("email"=>"adem@email.com", "issue"=>"asp", "username"=>"genc");
```

The number of values to change may vary.

Comment: And what's the logic here? What values should stay and what values should be removed?

Comment: im unsure what are you trying to do, a simple foreach should suffice on this one if it is what i think it is (overwrite values) and use the key, or a simple union `+` array2 on array1 would also work

Comment: Sounds like you want [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) which "Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. ." ie  in your case you could write  `$newArr = array_merge($source_array, $values_to_be_changed_array)`

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
  $source_array = ["email"=>"email@email.com", "name"=>"adem", "last_name"=>"genc", "username"=>"ademgenc", "age"=>"40", "issue"=>"php", "version"=>"12,50", "user_group"=>"2", "created"=>"2020-09-02 10:58:54"];

  $values_to_be_changed_array = array("email"=>"adem@email.com", "issue"=>"asp", "username"=>"genc");

  $new_array = array_replace($source_array,$values_to_be_changed_array);

  print_r($new_array);
```

Output with :

```
  Array
    (
        [email] => adem@email.com
        [name] => adem
        [last_name] => genc
        [username] => genc
        [age] => 40
        [issue] => asp
        [version] => 12,50
        [user_group] => 2
        [created] => 2020-09-02 10:58:54
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the value by this :

```
$a1=array($source_array["name"],"<old_name>");
$a2=array($source_array["name"],"<new_name>");
print_r(array_replace($a1,$a2));
```

Check this..